Not able to install Docker File on RHEL 8.10 vm
I am getting a really annoying problem with using Docker on RHEL 8.10 when using the docker pull command.
When I use this command and it runs the extraction towards the end it fails with the error 'failed to register layer: write/user/share/: no space left on the device'.
There is plenty of space on the VM there is 1TB of space. When I run docker info, it tells me that the storage driver is overlay2 and the backing file system is xfs and supports d_type true.
I have tried changing the basesize but this errors when running dockerd because of the overlay2.
So, does anyone know how to fix this? The compressed docker file is about 3Gb. There are no other images or containers on the VM. It is all new
